# Create table and call it from sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function which creates a new temporary table. For creating the table I use `execute immediate`. When I run my function in oracle sql developer everything is ok; the function creates the temp table without errors. But when U use SQL:

```
Select function_name from table_name
```

I get an exceptions:

```
ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.GET_USERS", line 10
14552. 00000 -  "cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML "
*Cause:    DDL operations like creation tables, views etc. and transaction
       control statements such as commit/rollback cannot be performed
       inside a query or a DML statement.
```

Update

Sorry, write from tablet PC and have problems with format text. My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_USERS 
(
    USERID IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
    request VARCHAR2(520) := 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ';
BEGIN
    request := request || 'temp_table_' || userid || 
            '(user_name varchar2(50), user_id varchar2(20), is_administrator varchar2(5)') ||
            ' ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (request);
    RETURN 'true';
END GET_USERS;
```

Comment: Is there some code we aren't seeing? What is line 10?

Comment: Use the edit feature to add the code to your original post, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: I think the error you get is because you try to Execute a function that creates a table inside a query.
You can't do that. Since you arleady created the table why do you try to call your function again?

Comment: Inside a query? Sorry, i'm not very strong in sql. This temp table using for return results to client. Or this mean, or use long string on the out of my procedure which we will have parse on client side. This specifics of the problem. The table is created only for the transfer of the result, if you call another procedure, it will be deleted and re-created with the right structure.

Comment: So you created the table and you want to select it in order to see the results?
In that case then you just use:
Select * from temp_table_userid

after you have executed the function and your table is created of course.

Comment: Thank you. Hurry and made a mistake. Corrected

Comment: No-no-no. In this moment my function only create table, no more. If i right understand comand "select get_users("123") from help" (table name for example, 123 in single ") starting my function, function must create table temp_table_123. But when i use this request i get an exceptions. When i run this function from oracle sql developer (click button run, i dont now how working this button) function are worked and created this table.

Comment: That's what I was saying. If you use "Select get_users(123) from help"
You WILL get an exception and the reason is because "Select something From something" is a Query. And get_users is a function that Creates a Table. 
You cannot Create a table from Inside a Query.
You can create an SQL Plus Script to do it if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will now try to understand how and what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested below solution on Oracle 10g XE, it works for me.

Create function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_USERS 
(
    USERID IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
    request VARCHAR2(255) := 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ';
BEGIN
    request := request || 'temp_table_' || userid || 
            '(user_name varchar2(50), user_id varchar2(20), is_administrator varchar2(5))' ||
            ' ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE request;
    RETURN 'true';
END GET_USERS;
```

Run function:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
 RESULT  VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
   RESULT:=gET_USERS('ADMIN3');
   dbms_output.put_line(result);
END;
```

and select from temporary table:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table_admin3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is explicit:

> ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML

In Oracle, you can't commit inside a query. A likely explanation is that it would make no sense since a query in Oracle is atomic (either succeeds entirely or makes no change) and this couldn't work if you commit in the middle of a DML. For a select query, all rows must be returned from a single logical point-in-time and if you commit in the middle of a select you would have inconsistent results.

Since DDL in Oracle issue an implicit commit, you can't make DDL inside a query.

This should not be a problem in your case though: SQL server-like temporary tables are not equivalent to the **GLOBALLY** temporary table in Oracle. There is a reason why temp tables in Oracle are always prefixed with `GLOBALLY`: they are visible to all sessions although the data in the temporary table is private to each session.

In Oracle creating a temporary table is a relatively expensive operation and you should not create individual temporary tables: all sessions should that do the same job should use the same common structure. Instead of creating multiple temporary tables, in Oracle you should create the table once and reuse it in all procedures. If you are going to need it later, why drop it?

In any case, if you decide to do multiple DDL that depend upon a SELECT, you could do it in a PLSQL block instead of a SELECT query:

```
DECLARE
   l VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT col FROM tab) LOOP
      l := create_temp_table(cc.col);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thx. I have some different requests, each result of requesr have different structure. I have task: do all requests in db not to use tables and cols name in request from client side. For do it without long string with results of current request i use tmp tables for each user. For all requests from user1 i use 1 tmp-table. because of the different structure I have to re-create the table for each new request. I believe that the problem - monkey work, but nothing I can do about it, and come up with a better solution. Thx.

Comment: Global temporary tables are situational in Oracle: in many cases they are not needed since Oracle manages to run correlated subqueries efficiently. Example: Instead of doing 3 inserts into temp and return the temporary tables, just run a single query with UNION ALL. For further reading, there is this good discussion on [askTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15826034070548)